# Сообщение о достижении максимального числа проверок

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Сейчас отображается такое сообщение:

> Спасибо! Сегодня вы проверили 20 голосов за закрытие. Заходите еще через 5 часов, чтобы продолжить проверку.

Мне в нём не нравится сочетание "проверили 20 голосов" - ведь проверяются не голоса, а сообщения. Возможно, следует как-то переформулировать это сообщение?

Comment: На мой взгляд, звучит приемлемо, если подразумевается проверка голосов за закрытие вопросов.

Answer (score 3):

> Спасибо! Сегодня вы выполнили 20 проверок в очереди на закрытие. Заходите еще через 5 часов, чтобы продолжить проверку.

// Заодно, после чисел надо поставить неразрывные пробелы, а не обычные.

Answer (score 3):

на всякий случай — ссылки на переводы:

[tx 3638](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265461) (вариант: one) *Спасибо! Сегодня вы проверили $numReviews$ голос за закрытие. Заходите еще $when$, чтобы продолжить проверку.*

[tx 5628](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267675) (вариант: few) *Спасибо! Сегодня вы проверили $numReviews$ голоса за закрытие. Заходите еще $when$, чтобы продолжить проверку.*

[tx 5629](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267676) (вариант: many) *Спасибо! Сегодня вы проверили $numReviews$ голосов за закрытие. Заходите еще $when$, чтобы продолжить проверку.*